# how to see the complete log of a embedded/code-started jetty server?

Tags: logging, jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I have the following code snippet to start a jetty server:

```
    server = setupSecureServer(8089, 8447, true);

    WebAppContext serverContext = new WebAppContext();
    serverContext.setContextPath("/foo");
    serverContext.setWar("/server/webapps/bar.war");
    server.setHandler(serverContext);

    server.start();
```

The issue is, although the above can start a jetty server, i'm seeing HTTP 503 when hitting its services.

My **question** is, is there a way to see the complete log of the jetty server, to help with the issue?

Currently there are log4j logs, but it does not contain the details of the 503 error.

The `log4j.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true"
                     xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

   <appender name="consoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p - [%C{1}:%L] %m%n"/>
      </layout>
   </appender>
   <root>
      <level value="ALL"/>
      <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
   </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

---

For completeness, the details of the `setupSecureServer()` method:

```
    public static Server setupSecureServer(final int port, final int sslport, final boolean clientAuth) {
        final SslConnectionFactory sslConnectionFactory =
                sslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory(clientAuth));
        final HttpConnectionFactory httpsConnectionFactory = httpsConnectionFactory(httpConfig(sslport));
        return sslConnectedServer(port, sslport, sslConnectionFactory, httpsConnectionFactory);
    }

    public static SslConnectionFactory sslConnectionFactory(final SslContextFactory contextFactory) {
        return new SslConnectionFactory(contextFactory, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1.toString());
    }

    public static SslContextFactory sslContextFactory(final boolean clientAuth) {
        final String keyStoreFile = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore");
        final String keyStorePassword = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword");
        final String trustStoreFile = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore");
        final String trustStorePassword = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword");

        final SslContextFactory contextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
        contextFactory.setKeyStoreType("JCEKS");
        contextFactory.setKeyStorePath(keyStoreFile);
        contextFactory.setKeyStorePassword(keyStorePassword);
        contextFactory.setNeedClientAuth(clientAuth);
        contextFactory.setTrustStorePath(trustStoreFile);
        contextFactory.setTrustStoreType("JCEKS");
        contextFactory.setTrustStorePassword(trustStorePassword);

        contextFactory.setTrustAll(true);

        return contextFactory;
    }

    public static HttpConnectionFactory httpsConnectionFactory(final HttpConfiguration config) {
        final HttpConfiguration sslConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration(config);
        sslConfiguration.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer());
        return new HttpConnectionFactory(sslConfiguration);
    }

    public static HttpConfiguration httpConfig(final int sslport) {
        final HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.setSecureScheme("https");
        config.setSecurePort(sslport);
        config.setOutputBufferSize(32786);
        config.setRequestHeaderSize(8192);
        config.setResponseHeaderSize(8192);
        return config;
    }

    public static Server sslConnectedServer(final int port, final int sslPort, final SslConnectionFactory sslConnectionFactory,
            final HttpConnectionFactory httpsConnectionFactory) {
        final Server server = new Server(port);
        final ServerConnector sslConnector = new ServerConnector(server, sslConnectionFactory, httpsConnectionFactory);
        sslConnector.setPort(sslPort);
        server.addConnector(sslConnector);
        return server;
    }
```

Comment: Jetty does not use log4j, and your description of the problem hints that it does, but your have provided no details on how you set that up.   At this point your question seems to be in conflict with itself.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt you are right in that log4j is separate from jetty. after debugging, i found the root reason is a missing `-D` VM arguments